# XmlNode xml xpath

Tags: c#, xml, html-agility-pack

I have myself a small C# console application that uses the `System.Xml` namespace as well as the `HTMLAgilityPack` library, my program is trying to scrape product variant information from a specific webpage, but I face an unusual issue. My program appears to be skipping over a certain HTML tag?

Here is the HTML code that I am pulling down

```
<option value="0">Select a size</option>
<option value="5">686 x 1981mm, 35mm Thick: &pound;143.01</option>
<option value="7">762 x 1981mm, 35mm Thick: &pound;143.01</option>
<option value="9">838 x 1981mm, 35mm Thick: &pound;143.01</option>
```

Here is my code for parsing the above HTML

```
if (vars != null && vars.Count > 0)
{
    int loc = 1;

    foreach (XmlNode item in vars)
    {
        // Get the <option> ... </option> contents
        string name = item.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//option[{0}]", loc)).GetInnerTextFromNode();
        string value = item.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//option[{0}]", loc)).GetAttributeFromNode("value");
        loc++;
    }
}
```

For some reason my code is skipping over the second  tag so I end up with 3 results instead of 4, ignoring it as if it does not exist. Does anybody know why this would be??

I apologize if my description is terrible!

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you for sure the the index of child nodes - what you're indexing with [loc] - is zero-based.
I'm not sure why a consistently second node would be skipped without more info.

But have you tried starting with loc=0 ?